# How to fill a group tableView cell with an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm using a group table view to show user settings, and i want to show an image in one of the cells.
As you all know the group table view cell has rounded corners, so I want my image to also be with the same rounded corners filling the entire cell.

How can I set an image to fill the cell with the same rounded corners?
When i try to set an image with the cell's bounds it fills the entire rect (from x=0) not the cell's rect (the cell's rect start with some x offset and has rounded corners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u have UIImageView in Cell then u can do this as each layer can have a corner radius set, this will give you just what you want:

implementation is below:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //......
    ///.......
    cell.yourImgView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    cell.yourImgView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0]; //according to your requirement
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

one of the way would be to use :

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"cellImage.png"];
```

Comment: this will cover the cell's rounded corners